# Cakephp order by filed list

Tags: php, cakephp

How can i define order by field list in cakephp paginate function

like

```
$this->paginate = array(
                        'conditions' => array('Page.provider_id' => $this->provider['Provider']['id']),
                        'order'      => array("FIELD(Page.id,$ids)")
                    );
```

where $ids contains 22,24,29,30,23,25,28,26,27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ids = implode(',', $ids);
$this->paginate = array(
                    'conditions' => array('Page.provider_id' => $this->provider['Provider']['id']),
                    'order'      => "FIELD(Page.id,$ids)"
                );
```